Unix terminal flashes white on autocomplete
When I work with a terminal via ssh and press Tab button my screen is flickering white.
Is there a way to disable it?

I connect to a Ubuntu server via putty.
My shell is Zsh but I have the same behavior in Bash.
I turned off the bell in putty but it didn't help.

I don't know what causes this.


That's a "Visible Bell" from the Linux terminal, created by completion indicating "more choices" by issuing a ^G (ASCII BEL 007 0X07). You can access the "Visible Bell" setting in the Linux terminal settings.

@waltinator thanks! It helped!

User @waltinator helped me.
They said that this feature is called 'Visible Bell' and controlled by ^G (ASCII BEL 007 0X07)
I was able to disable the flickering in zsh by adding the line unsetopt BEEP to my .zshrc file.
It just disables all bells.
In bash I was able to disable the flickering by adding the line set bell-style none to the .inputrc file.
Thanks!

See also info screen Bell for how the bell behaviour can be customized in GNU screen specifically (which the title of your terminal emulator window suggests you may be using).

@stéphane-chazelas thanks! I'll definitely check it

I'm not entirely certain that this is what happens. It could be that the app emits a BEL byte, like the command tput bel does. This typically results in an audible bell, but a terminal emulator might decide to override it and flash its canvas instead. But it also could be that the app emits the escape sequence that switches to reverse video, and a bit later on it changes back to normal video, like tput flash does (try also: tput flash | cat -v, infocmp | grep flash). I don't know which of these two happened to you, a script recording is probably the easiest way to tell.
